# NDK or SDK for image processing with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

We are developing an eye tracker for android. We are in the research phase and we need to decide if we will do the image processing part using the SDK or the NDK.

I would like to ask if the performance impact will be that much using the SDK.

Also, since we don't have experience with the NDK we were wandering how easy or difficult it is to set it up and start using it.

Thanks

Comment: *"... we were wondering how easy or difficult it is to set up and start using [the NDK]"* - Familiarize yourself using a book like [Android Native Development Kit Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/android-native-development-kit-cookbook). The modified build system is the most frustrating part (for me). Its not well documented for some tasks.